# neo4j data science library causes failure to start

Tags: neo4j

Installed neo4j and it is running fine.
Downloaded the data science library and copied it over to plugins.

neo4j refuses to start, does not give error on the start or console command, says it has started, but the log file shows the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting Neo4j database server at /home/aviroop/apps/neo4j-community-5.6.0/data/databases
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:271) ~[neo4j-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.build(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:207) ~[neo4j-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityBootstrapper.createNeo(CommunityBootstrapper.java:38) ~[neo4j-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:171) ~[neo4j-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.NeoBootstrapper.start(NeoBootstrapper.java:87) ~[neo4j-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:30) ~[neo4j-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.extension.GlobalExtensions@60921b21' failed to initialize. Please see the attached cause exception "Could not initialize class com.neo4j.gds.internal.AuraMaintenanceSettings".
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.init(LifeSupport.java:335) ~[neo4j-common-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.init(LifeSupport.java:57) ~[neo4j-common-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:86) ~[neo4j-common-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        at org.neo4j.graphdb.facade.DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.startDatabaseServer(DatabaseManagementServiceFactory.java:262) ~[neo4j-5.6.0.jar:5.6.0]
        ... 5 more
```

Did anyone face the same problem or knows a work around for the data science library to work?

If I remove the library neo4j-graph-data-science-2.3.1.jar from plugins folder neo4j works fine again

Comment: Can you include the version of the GDS library you installed? There may be a version mismatch.

Comment: I have been able to resolve this issue. It was indeed the version 2.3.1 which probably packaged some dependency on Aura related classes.
I have downloaded the 2.3.2 latest release from the following link 
https://github.com/neo4j/graph-data-science/releases/tag/2.3.2

now it works just fine